# Apt wildcard issue

Tags: apt, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Why does apt take file names in current directory as package names?
When i try to apt install boinc* i see "E: Unable to locate package boinc_ubuntu_7.16.6_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.sh"

Comment: The use of wildcards with apt can cause unexpected surprises...like the wrong package(s) being downloaded and installed. If you don't know the name of a package, there are plenty of existing tools to clarify and provide the exact name you seek. Those tools just take a moment to check.

Answer (score 3):

That's because wildcards are run in the shell, when you do

```
apt-get install foo-*
```

then the shell expands that to

```
apt-get install foo-bar.zip foo-doc.tex
```

depending on what's in the current directory, and it is that command which is run.  Generally, if a utility accepts wildcards, then you'd need to quote or escape them to stop this shell expansion

```
apt-get install 'foo-*'
```